# How do I style the "text focus line"-thingy with CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

How do I style this (for text input boxes) using CSS:

[image]

Also, what's the proper terminology for this thing?

Comment: What do you want to do to it?

Comment: You want cursor or blue border (focus) ?

Comment: For example, I'd like to make it thicker and change the color

Comment: I have added the code Clayton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Caret: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation

The browser has control over what it looks like, and you cannot style it besides the color, by styling the textbox in the way that @Manoj Kumar described. You can also return the position of it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
input:focus { 
 /* Your CSS Rules and Property */ 
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I think he's asking about changing the appearance of the stylus, not just the input box when it's visible.

Comment: `color: red;` changes the color of the stylus, but `font-weight: bold;` does not make it thicker

Comment: The stylus only appears when the input box is focused, so I think the element definition is correct.

Comment: This is not a standard change. Some browsers might do that but definitely not all. Nothing happens on my OS X Yosemite.

Comment: You will have to play with JavaScript. I find there is no CSS code for this, Clayton.